# Why does the loop ignore multiples of five?

Tags: java

I've just started learning Java, so my question is probably incredibly stupid.

I'm trying to solve one of the simpliest problems.

> Modify the previous program such that only multiples of three or five
>   are considered in the sum, e.g. 3, 5, 6, 9, 10, 12, 15 for n=17

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class NewProblem {
    public static void main (String[] args) {

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = scan.nextInt();

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            if (i % 5 == 0 || i % 3 == 0) {
                System.out.println(i);
            }
            else {
                i++;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

When I run it, it's showing only multiples of three. For example, here is the output for n = 17:

0
3
6
9
10
15

So it just ignores all multiples of 5.

What's wrong? 
Sorry again if the question is really stupid.

Comment: else contains i++ - you skip one element

Comment: during a for loop, `i` is automatically incremented when the loop starts again. When you do `i++` in your `else` statement, you're incrementing i of one and it is then incremented of one again due to the loop. For example, when `i = 1`, you fall on the `else` statement and get `i = 2`. Then, as the loop comes back around, you get `i = 3`. So `i = 2` was never really processed by your code, as it was immediately incremented.

Comment: `10` is multiple of `5` not `3`.

Answer (score 3):

The problem here is the `else` statement, which will add one to "i" if it's not divisble by `3` or `5`. Now, let's see what your method does if `n = 5`. First, the for loop runs with `0`, which is divisble by `5` and `3`, so the `for` loop runs again and now `i = 1`. `1` is not divisible by `5` or `3`, so the `else` statement is called, adding `1` to `i`, but since you have already set the `for` loop to do this, it will effectively add `2` to `i`, skipping `i = 2`, and you don't notice, because `2` shouldn't be printed out in the first place. Then `i = 3`, the `if` statement fires printing out like normal, the `for` loop fires again and this time `i = 4`. And `4` is not divisible by `3` or `5`, so the `else`statement fires again effectively adding `2` to `i` since the `for` loop adds one and the else statement one, resulting in `i = 6`, skipping `i = 5`. This is where the problem lies. Since the `for` loop already adds one to `i` every time it loops (the last section of the `for` statement says `i++`) resulting in some numbers being skipped. Simply remove the `else` statement and your code should work fine.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to increase i in the else block, it gets increased on every iteration by the for loop.